# where to get matlab libraries (libmat and libmx)

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, tracking, detection

I need to test and perhaps use libFeatureDetection.
But as indicated on the main page of the project, libFeatureDetection needs MATLAB (libmat, libmx) and OpenCV (core, imgproc, highgui).

So can you tell me where to get these libraries ?
Do I need to install MATLAB ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need full Matlab, just the [MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR)](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/).

You can grab the full blown installer package there. The installer is Java-based, though, and you need to have JRE installed in order to extract libraries from the package.

So, run the installer and install the MCR to some directory. When done, you will find the libraries in

```
<MCR installation dir>/matlab/v717/bin/glnx86/
```

P.S. There's also a nice guide on [linking with MCR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-and-linking-mat-file-programs.html).

Comment: Thank, I installed the MCR but it looks like I have to edit a lot of CMakelist.txt to integrate the correct path. In particular the FindMatlab.cmake file in the ./cmake dir.

Comment: I cannot find libmat in 2015 version, is there any older version you tried?

Comment: @dashesy 2015 doesn't have glnx86 since Matlab dropped 32bit support after 2013 (I think). Mine is R2014a and I got all the required files. My root folder for the installation is /opt/matlab/R2014a. From there MATLAB_BIN is the `bin/`, the includes are in `extern/include`, all the libs are in `bin/glnxa64/`, the MEXEXT_SCRIPT is at `bin/mexext` and finally the MEX_SCRIPT is at `bin/mex`. At least the building and linking of OpenCV 3 didn't break from that. Still haven't tested it inside Matlab though so I can't confirm it's working.

Comment: @rbaleksandar that is MATLAB installation, not MCR. MCR is free, but MATLAB needs license. Those headers are needed to build mex, even if MATLAB is not installed as long as the header&lib files could be see package can build (https://github.com/dashesy/CereLink). Headers can be used from Octave but link libraries need MATLAB installation.

Comment: I thought that with 2015 you meant the whole package not just the MCR. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the `CMakeLists.txt` file of [libFeatureDetection](https://github.com/elador/FeatureDetection/tree/master/libFeatureDetection) on github

`FIND_PACKAGE( MATLAB REQUIRED )`

means you need to have matlab installed.

Comment: Ok, but what to do if I cannot get a MATLAB license ?